# Set checkbox value in DataTables jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTable jquery plugin to show some data in my app...

I have this column definition:

```
 columns: [
  { "data" : "appName" },
  { "data" : "uuid" },
  { 
   "data" : "Enabled",
   'render': function(data, type, row)
   {
   console.log(data)
  return '<input type="checkbox" checked = "' + data + '" >';
   }
   }
```

and coresponding fields in array of objects passed from jquery. `console.log(data)` returns proper value, true of false for every record in table, but checkbox is always checked.

What i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return '<input type="checkbox" checked = "' + data + '" >';`

On this line you're adding the attribute `checked` hence it is always checked:

`return '<input type="checkbox"' + (data ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + '>';`

(Note that the value of `checked` does not need to be `"checked"` or even present, the attribute is the only thing that needs to be present, but it's generally preferred to use some meaningful value.)

Edit:

As your data appears to be a string rather than a boolean you'll need to compare data to `"true"`:

`return '<input type="checkbox"' + (data == "true" ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + '>';`

Comment: Not working. i always have either true or false in "data"... so it's always return checked...

Comment: do you have true or false or do you have a string representing them?